# Dynamic Module Classes in C++

Tags: c++, dynamic, module

I created, in a nutshell, a txt file converter.(basically converts text files removing comments etc into other text files)

I have created varius methods of converting the file(e.x. removing only the "#" symbols etc). In the future I would like to add other methods too but without touching the initial code. I want to add another class file in a subfolder and recompile the code. Then the new conversion method would appear in my program.

How I do that?

Comment: Are you looking for [guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/ms235636.aspx) like this? You question is not very clear, are looking for the ways for creating reusable codebase which can be plugged or unplugged from core or maybe a patterns incapsulating a core functuionality?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you use virtual member functions in a class, and/or template parameters, as **customization points**.

For run-time polymorphism (virtual member functions) this is called the **[open/closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle)**, after Betrand Meyer:

> **”** A class is closed, since it may be compiled, stored in a library, baselined, and used by client classes. But it is also open, since any new class may use it as parent, adding new features. When a descendant class is defined, there is no need to change the original or to disturb its clients.

For your particular case it would be natural to represent a “conversion method” as an object that you pass to a general text file converter functor object, which then uses it internally. Alternatively the “conversion method” can be a virtual function on the latter. This way of providing a procedure with customization points is called the **[template method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern)**.

Note: the word “template” in “template method pattern” does not refer to C++ templates, but rather to the notion of the customizable procedure as a template for each concrete adaption.

Comment: I think what you told me is not what I'm looking for. In a Greek forum I asked they told me to compile my extra source files with a wildcard "SOURCES = $(wildcard extensions/*.cpp)" and then the classes contributors make in the subfolders would register somewhere in order to get used. (if you can translate it from Greek www.insomnia.gr/topic/605154-modules-στην-c/#entry54765332)

Comment: Hm. I think more details about the problem are needed to give better advice.

Comment: @SpirosMitropoylos: Since an answer has already been posted to this one, and considering that changing the question would change the context for this answer (possibly invalidating it), I'd post a new question. ;-)